# react custom renderer - extend react-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, custom-renderer

I wanted to write a custom renderer for react. I want to use it one the web so it doesn't make sense to rewrite the whole thing since react-dom already exists.

Is it possible to write a custom renderer by just extending react-dom and only overwriting parts which make sense for my custom renderer?

E.g. i want to attach a key to every html element (div, p, span) which is rendered by react-dom.

I know how to write a custom renderer. What i don't know is if someone has tried extending the react-dom so that i don't have to copy paste allmost all react-dom code in my custom renderer. or call react-dom methods all over the place in my custom renderer. I hope the question is clear.

Please ask questions if something is not clear. I will try to clarify as much as possible

Comment: Anyone wants to give reasons for downvote?

Comment: I didn't down vote but I guess you're asking question without trying,it's my view only

Comment: How did people know i did not try?

Comment: Because in your post it's not mentioned(what you tried? any error you got? etc...)

Comment: I think better you edit your post with what you tried(code) and error(if you get anything) to avoid -ve votes

Comment: Some questions don't need code. I think this is one of those questions. I wanted to know if anyone has tried such a thing. I googled a lot and couldn't find any case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169436/discussion-between-andrew-and-mukesh-soni).

Comment: Ok! then your wish, what I thought I told to you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your, Andrew! Appreciate the time you took out to help.

Comment: No problem, Thanks to you too!